# fluent nhibernate one-to-one with base class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping, one-to-one

Suppose I have classes:

```
class Person
{
 String FirstName;
 String LastName;
 Pet Pet;
}

class Pet
{
 String Name;
 Person Owner;
}

class Cat : Pet
{
 Int32 MousesCaught;
}

class Dog : Pet
{
 Int32 CatsCaught;
}
```

And a mapping:

```
public class PetMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Pet>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Pet> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.Owner).PropertyRef(x => x.Pet).Constrained().Cascade.All();
        mapping.JoinedSubClass<Cat>("PetId");
        mapping.JoinedSubClass<Dog>("PetId");
    }
}
```

The problem is: **if there is Person with a Cat or a Dog in the DB the type of the Person.Pet is 'Pet{PetBroxyBlaBlaBla}'. So I cannot cast Person.Pet to type Cat (Person.Pet as Cat == null).**

```
    var person = this.Session.Get<Person>(personId);
    // person.Pet as Cat == null
```

But if I get this pet from DB before getting a Person the type is valid:

```
    var a = new this.Session.Get<Pet>(petId);
    var person = this.Session.Get<Person>(personId);
    // person.Pet as Cat != null
```

Is there are a way to tell NHibernate to init this property with a valid type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling lazy loading. It can be caused by [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/09/03/answer-the-lazy-loaded-inheritance-many-to-one-association-orm.aspx)